# "Not all code paths return a value" error message in method using foreach

Tags: c#

What troubles me is that. I cant figure it out. What i need to do is to search for a dude with name 'nazwisko' that is in list 'List'. If there is no such dude then i have to return null; The language is C#.

Any help appreciated.

```
Pracownik Search(string nazwisko)
{
    foreach (Pracownik pracownik in List)
    {
       if (List.Contains(pracownik))
          return pracownik;
       else
          return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the list declaration

Comment: Put `return null;` after the `foreach` code block, and see if the error message disappears.

Comment: It seems like what you *really* want to do is just write `return List.FirstOrDefault();`  The list will always contain the item, since you got the item from the list (barring custom comparer shenanigans or manipulation from another thread) so the `if` check and the `else` are pointless.

Comment: I added an answer and was going to add to it, but your code is just wrong on the face of it so I have deleted my answer. You're searching in the list by using elements *from* the list. Fix the code to at least be a sensible implementation. The answer for the "not all paths" is quite trivial, however.

Comment: You'll never hit your `else return null` case.  `List.Contains(pracownik)` will always be true - since it is a value in the list.

Comment: ¿What do you think should happen if `List` is empty and the `foreach` block is simply skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider the fact that the foreach statement may never be evaluated further in the event that the List is null.  Therefore:

```
 Pracownik Search(string nazwisko)
    {
        foreach (Pracownik pracownik in List)
        {
           if (List.Contains(pracownik))
              return pracownik;
           else
              return null;
        }
    // This is where the other path is.  What should it return if List is null?
     return null;
    }
```

I would check the syntax of your function, however.  I'm not sure it will do exactly what you intend.

edit:

```
Pracownik Search(string nazwisko)
    {
        foreach (Pracownik pracownik in List)
        {
           if (pracownik.Property?.Equals(naxwisko))
              return pracownik;
        }
    // This is where the other path is.  What should it return if List is null?
     return null;
    }
```

This may be better syntax- not sure what properties you want to compare or what your objects are.

Comment: With return null after foreach it gives me no errors but wont it always give me null like that ?

Comment: No.  That path will only return null if the list is null.  But check your syntax.. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 6):

If `List` doesn't contain any elements, nothing is returned:

```
Pracownik Search(string nazwisko)
{
    foreach (Pracownik pracownik in List)
    {
       if (List.Contains(pracownik))
          return pracownik;
       else
          return null;
    }

    // Adding this will correct
    return null;
}
```

That being said, there is no need for the foreach, as you're effectively always returning the first element.  This will do the same thing:

```
Pracownik Search(string nazwisko)
{
      return List.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

> What i need to do is to search for a dude with name 'nazwisko' that is in list 'List'.

If you intended to return the first matching element to your search string, I would recommend:

```
Pracownik Search(string nazwisko)
{
      return List.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == nazwisko);
}
```

Comment: No. What i need to do is to find specific guy from a list. If there is no guy that i am looking for then i have to return null. So there will be other guys but i need specific one :)

Comment: @Iska That's what my last piece of code does.  It returns the first "guy" who has a `Name` property which matches `nazwisko`.

Comment: nazwisko is a variable so it can be anything aaa sdasd derad etc.

Comment: @Iska Yes - My last version checks the "Name" property on "Pracownik" against that string - and returns the matching "Pracownik" member or null if none matches.

Answer (score 2):

All your code path does not return a value that is the reason.

```
   Pracownik Search(string nazwisko)
    {
       if (List == null) return null; //return if your list is null.

        foreach (Pracownik pracownik in List)
        {
           if (pracownik.someProp.Equals(nazwisko))
              return pracownik;
        }
        return null; //or something here
    }
```

In this case compiler doesn't know if List is going to be null or empty or not during compile time. In case List is null/empty your function never returns as it never is going to go into the code path inside your for loop that returns the value.

If you are using Linq, then you can rewrite as

```
   Pracownik Search(string nazwisko)
   {
      if(List == null) return null;

      return List.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.someProp.Equals(nazwisko));
   }
```

Comment: This is probably the answer, but it doesn't really explain why the compiler can't figure out that the code will never execute past the `foreach`.

Comment: -1 for incorrect foreach syntax

Comment: @RobertHarvey What if there are no elements in `List`?

Comment: If the list is null it throws an exception, and thus wouldn't need to return a value.  It's *only* a problem if the list is empty.

Comment: also, please format your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pracownik Search(string nazwisko)
{
    Pracownik retVal = null;
    foreach (Pracownik pracownik in List)
    {
       if (List.Contains(pracownik))
       {
          retVal = pracownik;
          break;
       }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is empty, then there will be no return. That's why you need to return null after the end of the foreach loop.
If you get an error, try defining the variable that receives the return of the function to nullable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the else in the foreach loop, otherwise you will return null immediately if the first pracownik doesn't exist in the List. Also, why are you passing the string parameter if it is not being used?

```
Pracownik Search(string nazwisko)
{
    foreach (Pracownik pracownik in List)
    {
       if (List.Contains(pracownik))
          return pracownik;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This still isn't really *fixing* the code.  You just got that item from the list, thus the list will *obviously* contain it.  The `if` will always be true, barring really contrived exceptions.

Comment: It will be used later.

Comment: @Servy Wow, I don't know how I didn't notice that. I was just concerned with fixing the error. But you are right, it almost seems like we should be doing something like `if (pracownik.SomeProp == nazwisko)` or something else...